# Error running tests, Target package is not specified in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, unit-testing

I am trying to run unit tests within an Android project within Android Studio. I have followed [this tutorial](http://rexstjohn.com/unit-testing-with-android-studio/) on how to do so, it seems pretty straightforward. 
I have  in AndroidManifest.xml declared as so

```
 <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="tests" />
```

The tag is not inside an Activity, but is inside the

When I go to run the tests, I get the error

**Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.example/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}**

And that no tests were found.

So far I have only one test class I am trying to run, I believe this is set up correctly

```
public class ItemTests extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    private Item testItem = new Item("Car");
    public void testGetFoodItemName(){
        assertEquals("Car", testItem.getName());
    }

}
```

Any help would be fantastic! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following to run tests.

add the following to build.gradle

```
android { 

    ....

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }

    ....
}
```

1) make a directory in src with name `test` as specified above.

2) further make a directory `java` inside `test`. You will notice color of `java` folder is green.

3) insider `src/test/java/` you can put your `ItemTests` class and other classes.

4) Right click class `ItemTests` -> Run `ItemTests` -> Click `ItemTests` with android logo to run as android test case.